# Quiero saber si se pueden pasar dos variables a una tabla de primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo una tabla de primefaces donde utilizo una variable pero me hace falta pasarle otra variable. Quisiera saber si eso se puede hacer

Comment: si pudieran responderme lo antes posible se los agradeceria es que estoy trabajando en mi tesis y estoy contra el tiempo

Comment: a que variables te refieres? la coleccion de objetos a mostrar? Si es asi, no veo como podrias pasarle 2 colecciones

Comment: @Jose Alejandro Sanz Cuesta que es lo que quieres hacer??

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a un datatable, este recibe una lista o un map de objetos para poder visualizar. el atributo value="" solamente puede ser declarado una vez. Deberías de mostrar el código de lo que pretendes hacer, creo que la pregunta deja muchas dudas. Quedo al pendiente!!!!